# Can't Generate Google Configuration File

Tags: ios, configuration, google-plus-signin

I went to the Google Developer page to create the sign in for IOS and when it comes to generating the conf file, I get to this page and it seems like it's stuck here.

[image: Error pic]

I've tried every browser: Chrome, IE, Firefox, and Opera (Without ad block or pop up blocker) and it doesn't move.

Comment: @madoke Any ideas on what's going on?

Comment: I just check it and it looks like it is the website problem. To work around it, you can open the developer console of chrome, and it will show 2 red lines. You click the first error message's link to open it in new tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that I did not authorize Google API Key. From the GOogle Developer's portal.